# Can I set up some sort of local, home-only "cloud computing" system - where a computer offloads some of its computational load to another?

Tags: networking, windows-8, debian

I have a Windows 8 laptop that wheezes under the strain of just a few open youtube tabs (1.0 Ghz processor), and a Linux (Debian stable "wheezy") desktop (3.4 Ghz, 8 cores) that is mostly idle unless I am doing programming work. Can I set up some sort of internal "cloud system", where I can get some of the laptop's computation work done by the desktop (with data being sent over my LAN network)?  What sort of tools and keywords should I be thinking of googling? (I am a total newbie)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything that general.

If you are specifically talking about youtube slowness, you may see some improvement by running some form of desktop sharing from the linux machine to the laptop and running the browser on the linux machine while viewing from the laptop.

Search for "RDP server linux" and see if that helps.

Peek at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3934/is-it-possible-to-use-remote-desktop-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu